# Самая современная литература, статьи, примеры по новому OpenGL

Tags: opengl

Что можете посоветовать на русском и английском языке?

Comment: Всё это уже известно. Хотелось бы более тщательно ознакомиться по OpenGL 3.3 и выше.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала надо понять основы графики. Старые добрые [opengl.org](http://opengl.org/), [gamedev.ru](http://gamedev.ru/) и [gamedev.net](http://gamedev.net/) никто не отменял. + читайте литературу по шейдерам, которые являются отдельной темой.

**UPD**

Случайно наткнулся на интересный цикл статей [Уроки по OpenGL 3](http://code.google.com/p/gl33lessons/)

Comment: Очень неплохие уроки. Жаль, что давно не обновлялись. Был на этом ресурсе пару месяцев назад и с тех пор без перемен.